# How to make JavaScript to only push unique elements inside an array while also reaching desired length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have made a program that is supposed to find all possible permutations of how a cricket team can be made I also did some math to find out that the total permutations are supposed to be 864. So I want my array of all arrays to be 864 in length and includes all permutations too. I tried to this using if case but it doesn't seem to work. What I want is that all arrays are unique.
My JavaScript code:

```js
console.time("your code took");
let totalArrays = [];
function randomReturn(maxNum) {
   let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * maxNum) + 1;
   return parseFloat(randomNumber);
}
function arrayMaker() {
   let currentArray = [
      randomReturn(3),
      randomReturn(5),
      randomReturn(5),
      randomReturn(5),
   ];
   let sumOfNums = currentArray.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
   if (sumOfNums != 11) {
      return arrayMaker();
   } else if (sumOfNums == 11) {
      return currentArray;
   }
}
function main() {
   let team = arrayMaker();
   if (!totalArrays.includes(team)) {
      totalArrays.push(team);
      totalArrays.sort()
   } else if (totalArrays.includes(team)) {
      main();
      totalArrays.sort();
   }
   while (totalArrays.length < 864) {
      main();
   }
}
main();
for (let i = 0; i < totalArrays.length; i++){
   document.write("["+totalArrays[i]+"],")
}
console.log(totalArrays.length)
console.timeEnd("your code took");
```

You can see I have made an if statement that checks if the total arrays includes this array but it is not working. If you have any other way to this I would love to it.
Thanks for reading my query!

Comment: I don't understand why you want to random guess these arrays, only to sort them. That means that if you solve the `includes` bug, and ever get there (I think it will take ages), the outcome will always be the same. So why not generate that array in a non-random way?

Comment: @trincot i am not able to make logic to be able to achieve you see i just want all those arrays and i know the random method is not the most efficient way to do this but how do i come with something that can have all the logic? I you can help me it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare arrays like that, because `[1,1,1,1,1] != [1,1,1,1,1]`. Each array you create is a separate object, and when comparing them, you compare object references.

Moreover, since near the end you want the random generator to produce the only remainig array that is still allowed, you risk getting into a very long guess-retry cycle, that consumes the stack (as you use recursion).

Yet, the outcome is deterministic: it is sorted, and has all the unique permutations (with sum 11). So you are better off excluding the random factor in your algorithm. There is nothing random about the desired outcome.

So implement it like this:

```js
let perms = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   for (let j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
       for (let k = 1; k <= 6; k++) {
           let m = 11 - i - j - k;
           if (m >= 1 && m <= 6) {
               perms.push([i, j, k, m]);
           }
       }
   }
}
console.log(perms.length);
```

Note that there are indeed 4 * 6 * 6 * 6 combinations possible, but of those only 88 have a sum of 11. So the above produces 88 arrays.

### About Random

The above does not use random numbers, but I still wanted to comment on the code you used:

```
function randomReturn(maxNum) {
   let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * maxNum) + 1;
   return parseFloat(randomNumber);
}
```

This way of producing random numbers is not homogeneous:

The probability to generate a 1 is not equal to the probability to generate a 2. This is because a 1 can only be achieved by rounding down, not rounding up. The same happens with getting `maxNum+1` as result: it has lower probability as it can only be achieved by rounding up, not by rounding down.

Also, it is confusing that `maxNum` is actually one less than the maximum value that this function can return.

Finally, it is not necessary to call `parseFloat`, as the generated number already is a number. Calling `parseFloat` will perform an unnecessary conversion to string and back to number.

A better function would not use `round` but `floor`:

```
function randomReturn(maxNum) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum) + 1;
}
```

And you would need to pass the adjusted -- really maximum -- argument:

```
randomReturn(4)
```

and

```
randomReturn(6)
```

Comment: He is adding 1 to the range so its 1-4 and 1-6 but I am not sure if that is what he wants though

Comment: Yes, updated. His random generator is not homogeneous.

Comment: @AbdullahRazzaki is correct it is because each cricket team actually has 22 players and only 11 play out of them thats why each team has a configuration of [4, 6, 6, 6] usually 4 wicket-keepers, 6 batsmen, bowlers and all rounders please try to edit your answer a little bit and i might accept this answer! thank you so much

Comment: Thanks @trincot your points are correct i will definitely try to improve my code using them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. There are total 864 permutations but only some of them have sum of 11. You don't need random guessing you can easily do it with for loops like below. I have added the conditions for k and m to reduce wasteful iterations

```js
const result = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
for (let j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
    for (let k = 1; k <= (10 - j - i) && k <= 6; k++) {
        for (let m = 1; m <= (11 - j - i - k) && m <= 6; m++) {
            if (i + j + k + m === 11) {
                result.push([i, j, k, m]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
console.log(result, result.length);
```

Comment: this answer is good but that is not how permutations work you are simply counting up but permutations are more than that. I still thank you for reading my query!

Comment: i do think that i am wrong if i am then i am extremely sorry

Comment: @DragonSoup what do you mean? it produces your expected output

Comment: I am actually wrong but let me show you how permutations are made check this video https://youtu.be/KWZGSsWESM8 you will see

Comment: Yes I understand but you don't need all permutations you only need an sorted list of arrays according to your conditions with sum 11. it would be wasteful if you generate all the permutations first and then filter out the ones with sum 11.

Comment: hmmm.... now that i think about it, you are correct as well. I was wrong i suppose

Comment: This should be an acceptable answer instead of generating random numbers to achieve the result.

Comment: @DragonSoup add my k condition to trincon's answer it will reduce iterations

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `Set()`

Example :

```
const mySet1 = new Set()
//instead of array.push(1);
mySet1.add(1)
mySet1.add(1)
```

At the end if you want to convert it to array, just write one line

```
var array = [...mySet1]
```

For detailed reference about Set api, use mdn [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

But set supports only primitive values, for reference checks, Arrays are not primitives.

**One trick is to convert array to primitives (string)**

1. Sort the Array `arr.sort()`
2. `strigify` the array `JSON.stringify(arr)`
3. Add that to the `Set`

each entry of set will be an string (representing an array)
later on you can deconstruct the array back using `JSON.parse(arrString)`

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided had 2 main problems:

1. Includes method compares references only so that [1,1,1,1] doesn't necessarily equal [1,1,1,1]. I replaced it with some().
2. The maximum arrays you can have are 88 not 864

Here is a working code:

```js
console.time("your code took");
let totalArrays = [];
function randomReturn(maxNum) {
   let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * maxNum) + 1;
   return parseInt(randomNumber);
}
function arrayMaker() {
   let currentArray = [
      randomReturn(3),
      randomReturn(5),
      randomReturn(5),
      randomReturn(5),
   ];
   let sumOfNums = currentArray.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
   if (sumOfNums != 11) {
      return arrayMaker();
   } else if (sumOfNums == 11) {
      return currentArray;
   }
}
function main() {
   while (totalArrays.length < 88) {
      let team = arrayMaker();
     if (!totalArrays.some(elem => team[0] === elem[0] && team[1] === elem[1] && team[2] === elem[2] && team[3] === elem[3] )) {
        totalArrays.push(team);
     } 
   }
   totalArrays.sort();
}
main();
for (let i = 0; i < totalArrays.length; i++){
   document.write("["+totalArrays[i]+"],")
}
console.log(totalArrays.length)
console.timeEnd("your code took");
```

Comment: ohh now that i think about it the first point does make sense! I was so wrong. i had to check if all elements of the array match all the elements of the other array and not just put an equal sign. I really thank you for letting me know!

Comment: There is no need to generate the result by random numbers. OP just wants all the permutations.